# How to load scripts and style for frontend and admin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am quote confused about loading js an css for frontend and admin areas.

I see there is:

`wp_enqueue_style()`
`wp_enqueue_script()`

How can I load them separately for frontend and backend?

I see there is a hook for js as follows `'admin_enqueue_scripts'` but I cannot see `'admin_enqueue_styles'`.  Is there something for the frontend?

Sorry but I am gettng very confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress, many functions have hooks with an exact or similar name. In this case, `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the hook you want to use to queue JS and CSS for the frontend via the `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` functions. `admin_enqueue_scripts` is the hook to do the same with the same functions but for the backend.